# The reason for the different answer in a benchmark run

Tags: cplex

When i run a benchmark on Cplex with concert C++ on two systems the optimal solution is the same but one of the systems  in consul shows 284 nodes and the other one shows 414 nodes?
I am sure that i run one code on the both systems. What is the reason for this difference? Is it multiple Optimal Solutions? If yes, How do I get the same number of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and is known as "performance variability". As soon as you change something in the system or algorithm configuration (cores, threads, operating system, parameters) you can get different solution paths.

This means that if there are alternate optimal solutions then you may get alternate solutions. If there is only one optimal solution it may take a different number of nodes to find it.

The only way to guarantee the exact same behavior between two solves is to use the exact same configuration on the exact same hardware.